# Apache2 won't Gzip my js/css

Tags: apache, gzip

My server doesn't seem to gzip my css and javascript files. It works for HTML.

Here's my config: http://pastie.org/1105941
And here's my result: http://i35.tinypic.com/audv0k.jpg

Also tested Google Page Speed, and made Apache2 log the compression results. They say the same.

What could be wrong here, since it does compress the HTML?

Comment: What's with the `BrowserMatch` statements?

Comment: I read some blogs (more than one) pointing out that older browsers have trouble serving gzipped content, and thus filtering those browsers out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, it is working ... using firefox and the webdeveloper plugin the response for both css and js reports gzip

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow I feel stupid! Yes it works. I changed the config file for the production server, while later testing the staging one! Haha :D

Answer (score 1):

Download a CSS file with a browers and check the content type. Chances are that it's `application/binary` or something. If that is the case, you must tell the server that `*.css` should be sent as `text/css`, etc:

```
AddType text/css .css
```